# How to apply dropout in tensorflow to multidimensional tensors?

Tags: tensorflow, dimensions, tensor

I have a 3D tensor called X, of shape say [2,20,300] and I would like to apply dropout to only the third dimension. However, I want the dropped elements to be the same for the 20 instances (second dimension) but not necessarily for first dimension.

What is the behaviour of the following:

```
tf.nn.dropout(X[0], keep_prob=p)
```

Would it only act on the dimension that I want? If so, then for multiple first dimensions, I could loop over them and apply the above line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation of [`tf.nn.dropout`](http://devdocs.io/tensorflow~python/tf/nn/dropout):

> By default, each element is kept or dropped independently. If
>   noise_shape is specified, it must be broadcastable to the shape of x,
>   and only dimensions with noise_shape[i] == shape(x)[i] will make
>   independent decisions

So it is as simple as:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

data = np.arange(300).reshape((1, 1, 300))
data = np.tile(data, (2, 20, 1))

data_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(data.astype(np.float32))
data_op = tf.nn.dropout(data_op, 0.5, noise_shape=[2, 1, 300])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    data = sess.run(data_op)

for b in range(2):
    for c in range(20):
        assert np.allclose(data[0, 0, :], data[0, c, :])
        assert np.allclose(data[1, 0, :], data[1, c, :])

print((data[0, 0, :] - data[1, 0, :]).sum())
# output something != 0 with high probability#
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. That's the behaviour I was after. But this does add noise into the data right? when I print from your code, the values are from np.arrange(300) + some noise.

Comment: Dropout-Documentation: "With probability x, outputs are scaled up by `1 / keep_prob`, otherwise outputs `0`.  The scaling is so that the expected sum is unchanged." Original sum is 1794000, so the output should have approx. the same sum.

Comment: As an aside, I would prefer the use of `tf.layers.dropout` to `tf.nn.dropout`, since the interface of the first one is consistent with the other layers.